# plot bands in x-axis is not working on time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have used plot Bands high chart in x-axis based on time. I have given `from: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 20)` and  `to: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 23),` but it is not showing the plot Band. I have tried some different formats but those are also not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/v1oazypd/4/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a category type xAxis so you must use `number` for the plot band [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands.from)

```
plotBands: [{
  from: 7,
  to: 9,
  color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
}]
```

[Fiddle - category](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/584oph2x/)

**OR**

Forget categories and really use dateTime like this :

```
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  type: 'datetime',
  plotBands: [{
    from: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 8),
    to: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 10),
    color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
  }]
},
...
series: [{
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    name: 'test.html',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'circle' //No I18N
    },
    color: '#63cdca', //No I18N
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  }
]
```

[Fiddle - Datetime](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/584oph2x/1/)

Comment: @SaninFC, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.